# How to support production environnement by ASP.NET Core 2.2 app in Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, production-environment

I'm running my app built under (Visual Studio Code on Mac Mojave 10.14.14) on docker and i'm getting this error :

```
ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core – ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.
```

Most likely because I had the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development!

And also there is some code in the default public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) method in the Startup.cs file which checks for this.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
     app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
     app.UseHsts();
 }
```

Docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  site:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}site
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: site/Dockerfile
```

lanchSettings.json :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:18215",
      "sslPort": 44326
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "site": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any solutions please ?

Thank you

Comment: If you run project without hosting in docker? Will you see any error? Try to replace `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` with `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` to check the error message.

Comment: @TaoZhou Yes it was 'app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();' but it is not working, but without hosting in docker it works fine.

Comment: What is the error when using `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`?

Comment: @TaoZhou When i use `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` , i get this error :
`InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'sitehidamek.Models.MyKeysContext' has been registered.

CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)`

Comment: Share us your `Startup.cs`. How did you register `MyKeysContext`?